# Java Stream.sorted() gives wrong result

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have list `{"100","5","1","300","7"}` and when I use `stream().sorted()` for this list it's gives me the following result `{"1","100","300","5","7"}`. Looks like it's sorted only by first digit. What's wrong?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            "100","5","1","300","7"
));

list.stream().sorted().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e));
```

Comment: That is the correct sort for sorting strings.

Comment: Q: Looks like it's sorted only by first digit.  A: Yup.  It's sorting a *string* by the first *alphabetic character*!  If you want to sort differently, you'll need a custom [Comparitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).  It's actually pretty easy...

Comment: Like this? list.stream().sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2)).forEach(e -> System.out.println(e)); It's still not works.

Comment: By the way: unless you *really* need an `ArrayList`, you can simply say: `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("100","5","1","300","7");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list values are being sorted lexicographically. You could convert the values

```
list.stream().sorted((s1, s2)-> new Integer(s1).compareTo(new Integer(s2))).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Shorter and more efficient: `.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt))`

Comment: Or, if you don’t need the `String`s anyway: `list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);`